# A slidetoggle for columns in Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code:

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="col2" class="span0"></div>
    <div id="col1" class="span12">
        <a id="trig" class="btn btn-inverse">Reflow Me</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row-fluid div {
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease, margin 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 0.3s ease, margin 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: width 0.3s ease, margin 0.3s ease;
    transition: width 0.3s ease, margin 0.3s ease;
}

.row-fluid .span0 {
    width: 0%;
}

#col1 {
    background-color: #A6BFBA;
}

#col2 {
    background-color: #DE4124;
}

#trig {
    margin: 50px;
}

.row-fluid .span0 + [class*="span"]{
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

JS

```
$('#trig').on('click', function () {
    $('#col1').toggleClass('span12 span3');
    $('#col2').toggleClass('span0 span9');
});
```

How would you make the exact code above work for the slide toggle in Bootstrap 3.0?

Answer (score 4):

Haha.. Well that was fun.. And after a lot of trying I came up with something but the transition is still really ugly.  And there are no longer margins between spans in rows with bootstrap 3.  Anyway 30 minutes later and some scary looking code like the following.

```
$('#trig').on('click', function () {
  $('#trig').fadeOut(function(){
    $('#col1').toggleClass('col-xs-12 col-xs-3');
    if($('#trig').css('margin-left') == '-100px')
       $('#trig').css('margin-left','50px');
    else
       $('#trig').css('margin-left','-100px');
    if($('#col2').hasClass('col-xs-1')){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#col2').toggleClass('col-xs-1 col-xs-9');
        },25);  
    }
    else {
        $('#col2').toggleClass('col-xs-1 col-xs-9');  
    }  
    $('#trig').fadeIn();             
  });
});
```

This is all I could come up with.

http://www.bootply.com/91431